# Group with exactly $2$ elements of order $6$ has a normal subgroup of order $3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group with exactly $2$ elements of order $6$. Prove that $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $3$.

Since there is an element of order $6$, by Lagrange's Theorem, the order of $G$ must be a multiple of $6$. That means that both $2$ and $3$ are also divisors of the order of $G$, so, again by Cauchy's Theorem, $G$ must contain elements of order $2$ and order $3$ as well, respectively.

I suppose I'm not sure where to proceed from here. How can we use the fact that $G$ has *exactly* $2$ elements of order $6$ ? Would Sylow Theorems be helpful here at all ? I don't see how - since we don't know the exact order of $G$ here, which is when I'm used to using the Sylow Theorems.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is $G$ a finite group?

Comment: The conclusion that $|G|$ is a multiple of six does not follow from Cauchy’s Theorem (which says that if a prime $p$ divides $|G|$, then $G$ has an element of order $p$). It follows from Lagrange’s Theorem.

Comment: But $G$ is not necessarily a finite group so the discussions about $|G|$ are irrelevant. As others have pointed out, the two elements of order $6$ mus be self-inverse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, a characteristic subgroup of a normal subgroup is normal.

Now let $a$ have order $6$.  Then $a^5$ also has order $6$.  Hence conjugation by any element of $G$ takes $a$ to $a$ or $a^5$, by the assumption of only two elements of order six.  Hence $\langle a\rangle $ is invariant under conjugation,  hence normal.

Next, $a^2$ has order $3$.

But $\langle a^2\rangle $ is characteristic in $\langle a\rangle $ (since $\langle a\rangle $ is cyclic).

The result follows.

Comment: Why does $|a^5| = 6$ imply $\langle{a}\rangle$ being the only subgroup of order $6$?

Comment: @ClementYung see my edit.

Comment: Okay that's very clear. Thank you.

Comment: @ClementYung ok.  And thanks for pointing that out.